# Date set in tab Layout android

Tags: android, android-studio

I am getting trouble with setting dates in tab, where I have set Days names
Monday to Friday and I want to set date just below the text .

```
 Calendar mCal = Calendar.getInstance();
    int mYear = mCal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int mMonth = mCal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int mDay = mCal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setText("Monday\n" +mDay+"/"+mMonth);
        tabLayout.getTabAt(1).setText("Tuesday\n");
        tabLayout.getTabAt(2).setText("Wednesday\n");
        tabLayout.getTabAt(3).setText("Thursday\n");
        tabLayout.getTabAt(4).setText("Friday\n");



    TabLayout.Tab tab;
    int today = mCal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
    if(today == Calendar.MONDAY || today == Calendar.SATURDAY || today == Calendar.SUNDAY){
        tab = tabLayout.getTabAt(0);
        tab.select();
    }else if(today == Calendar.TUESDAY){
        tab = tabLayout.getTabAt(1);
        tab.select();
        tab.setText("Today's");
    }else if(today == Calendar.WEDNESDAY){
        tab = tabLayout.getTabAt(2);
        tab.select();
        tab.setText("Today's");
    }else if(today == Calendar.THURSDAY){
        tab = tabLayout.getTabAt(3);
        tab.select();
        tab.setText("Today's");
    }else if(today == Calendar.FRIDAY){
        tab = tabLayout.getTabAt(4);
        tab.select();
        tab.setText("Today's");
    }
```

It would be highly appreciate if you guyz show me where I need to do operation.Date should be increamental